# Install multiple elasticsearch versions on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, deb, development, elasticsearch

I have two projects using different versions of Elasticsearch, the first uses 0.9.x and the second will use 1.2.x. What would the best way to install both versions so I can work on the two projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Edit 2019-12-11**]: Docker is obviously the way to go now!

Answering to myself, I ended with simple installation scripts like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get remove elasticsearch
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-0.90.5.deb
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
sudo cp -R plugins /usr/share/elasticsearch
sudo cp elasticsearch.yml.0.90.5 /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
sleep 2;
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
```

Note that in the elasticsearch.yml file, the cluster name must be different to avoid conflicts:

**0.9.5**:

```
cluster.name: cluster_v0
```

**1.7.6**:

```
cluster.name: cluster_v1
```

And so on.

Comment: So you uninstalled other version. How do you manage to install both of them?

Comment: I don't use both, I install the version I need to use and then I reindex. It's very fast, it can be done in less than one minute with the "dev" data. (of course it's not so fast with a production database)

Answer (score 0):

//Get the first ElasticSearch version

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.6.10.tar.gz

tar -zxf elasticsearch-5.6.10.tar.gz
```

//Get the second ElasticSearch version you would like to install

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.8.2.tar.gz

tar -zxf elasticsearch-6.8.2.tar.gz
```

//Configure the elasticsearch.yml file as follows

```
vim elasticsearch-5.6.10/config/elasticsearch.yml

cluster.name: elastic_cluster1 
node.name: node-1 
node.master: true 
node.data: true 
transport.host: localhost 
transport.tcp.port: 9300 
http.port: 9200 
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

//Configure elasticsearch.yml file for another ES version

```
vim elasticsearch-6.8.2/config/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: elastic_cluster2
node.name: node-2
#node.master: true
node.data: true
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9304
http.port: 9204
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

//To start ElasticSearch Services from Terminal

```
cd elasticsearch-5.6.10
bin/elasticsearch -d


cd elasticsearch-6.8.2
bin/elasticsearch -d
```

//Verify the status and confirm the service is installed or not

```
ps -ef | grep elastic
```