# Multiple ElasticSearch (6 and 7) versions in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, php7, elasticsearch

I would like to install two Elasticsearch versions (**Elasticsearch 6.x**) and **Elasticsearch (7.x)**.

Does anyone know which is the best way for Ubuntu 18.04 so it should work for both projects?

I want ES to setup for PHP based projects that are running on php version 7.

**Ref.**
[Install multiple elasticsearch versions on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492755/install-multiple-elasticsearch-versions-on-12-04)

Comment: For answer - Refer this - https://askubuntu.com/a/1198616/636441